# Discussions are gone, so where can fans/users of a Facebook Page discuss posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I run a Facebook Page with over 23,000 fans.  I used to have users submit recipes to the discussions tab.  However, now that it is gone, I'm having difficulty finding a way to let users share recipes.

If they simply post it in the stream, it goes away much too quickly.  I've tried creating a new note with my personal account and tagging my page, but that does not make it show up in my pages "notes" section.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.